# IllegalStateException in VideoView's MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() from Expansion File

Tags: android, android-videoview, apk-expansion-files

I have an Expansion File (zip) full of mp4 videos that I'd like to play with the VideoView. When calling videoView.setVideoURI() it throws and IllegalStateException (prepareAsync called in state 1) in my VideoView's openVideo(). I retrieve the URI to the video from an extended APEZProvider class.

The expansion file got packed like below and renamed to "main.3.com.my.application.obb"

```
zip -r -0 [desiredZipFileName.obb] [folderWithVideos]
```

VideoView:

```
Uri uri = ExpansionAPEZProvider.buildUri("vid_intro.mp4");
videoView = (VideoView) activity.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

The Custom APEZ Provider class.

```
public class ExpansionAPEZProvider extends APEZProvider {

private static final String AUTHORITY = AndroidApplication.getApplication().getPackageName() + ".provider." + ExpansionAPEZProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return AUTHORITY;
    }

    public static Uri buildUri(String path) {
        StringBuilder contentPath = new StringBuilder("content://");
        contentPath.append(AUTHORITY);
        contentPath.append(File.separator);
        contentPath.append(path);

        String newPath = contentPath.toString();

        return Uri.parse(newPath);
    }
}
```

buildUri() returns an URI like this

> "content://com.my.application.provider.ExpansionAPEZProvider/vid_intro.mp4"

Provider in the Manifest:

```
<provider android:name=".ExpansionAPEZProvider"
        android:authorities="com.my.application.provider.ExpansionAPEZProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="mainVersion"
            android:value="3"/>
    </provider>
```

The StackTrace

```
    V/WindowManager(  749): Adding window Window{683bb62 u0 SurfaceView} at 13 of 21 (before Window{22e3dff1 u0 com.my.application/com.my.application.activity.StartActivity})
    I/MediaFocusControl(  749):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2335d19 req=1flags=0x0
    E/MediaPlayer(15769): prepareAsync called in state 1
    D/AndroidRuntime(15769): Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769): Process: com.my.application, PID: 15769
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769): java.lang.IllegalStateException
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:356)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:72)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:628)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    W/ActivityManager(  749):   Force finishing activity 1 com.my.application/.activity.StartActivity
    W/DropBoxManagerService(  749): Dropping: data_app_crash (1630 > 0 bytes)
    I/WindowManager(  749): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{2d07c562 ActivityRecord{3b01f344 u0 com.my.application/.activity.StartActivity t8900 f}} appWin=Window{683bb62 u0 SurfaceView} drawState=3
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. The zip/obb file must have been broken. I packed it again via terminal as described in the post above and now it works. Took me ages to find the problem. 
A FileNotFoundException or IOException instead of the IllegalStateException would have been more helpful to me to locate the problem.